# Как мне сделать запрос о студентах которые получили оценку в определонем диапазоне?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как мне сделать запрос  для выборки предметов и количестве тех кто учится, получивших их оценку более одного числа и менее другово.

Вот ссылка на онлайн комплилятор. Использован SQL Lite, но работаю в SQL Microsoft Managment Studio
https://onlinegdb.com/ZT7wvlB2I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, что-то такое

```
SELECT name, SUM(case when mark >= 4 and mark <= 7 then 1 else 0 end) AS x
FROM Subjects as s
LEFT join TeachersSubjects as ts on ts.SubjectId = s.id
LEFT join Marks as m on m.TeachSubId = ts.id
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @nerv1 если то, что надо, то ткните галку у ответа